# FMS server died daily while enable rtmfp

Tags: apache-flex, logging, crash, rtmfp, fms3

I have a fms 3 server runing a video chat room application. It goes well except everyday it will die once or twice. After restarting the fms server, everything goes working again.

I really need to know the reason why fms server can die.

I checked its log, i saw many 
"Server rejected an invalid flow."

Any hint will be greatest welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This error can be caused by making an attempt to make a P2P connection to the server's peer ID.  Connections to the server need to use

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/845685

> i believe the problem is that you are attempting to make a P2P connection to the server's peer ID; that is, something like

```
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(netConnection, netConnection.farID);

ns.play(...);
```

> under the covers, this will open a new RTMFP flow to the server that will appear to the server as a new incoming client, but the initial handshake will be incorrect (the first/only command message is "play" instead of "connect").  i see this on Cirrus all the time.
>
> it's possible that FMS doesn't account properly when rejecting these flows (leaving the connection count higher than it should be), or perhaps it leaves the flow open waiting for a "connect" message that will never come, so the connection count is legitimately higher than you think it is.
>
> in any case, make sure you're not opening a P2P stream to the server's peer ID.

However, this error may not actually be related to the crashes.  Additionally, are you even sure FMS is crashing and not just your application? If it's just your application, review your application logs (instead of the core FMS logs) and if you don't have anything useful add more logging to your application.

Comment: Hi, Neff, you are right, what die daily is my app, not the fms server.